# Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Tags: java, android

i am using SQLLITE In Android, i am getting this strange error at

```
long a1 = cursor.getLong(0);
```

i have checked Cursor for null, i am checking if cursor contains rows, i am moving the cursor on first row but still i am getting the below error

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

```
if ( cursor.getCount()>0)
            {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                           long a1 = cursor.getLong(0);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
```

Comment: What's your query like and how much data is there per result row?

Comment: put the entire function plz

Comment: @laalto it returns 1 row with 6 columns

Comment: And how much data is there? Bytes, not columns.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, i was having a blob column in the row which was filled with very large image.

Answer (score -1):

A long shot : if I recall correctly the column numbering in all JDBC features starts at ONE, not at ZERO.

Comment: This is not JDBC but Android SQLiteDatabase where the column indices are zero-based.

Comment: Then I can't help.  Sorry for the diversion.